# Is there a way in AWS to receive a cost breakdown for individual executions of an application?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm currently writing a thesis for which I have developed an application which utilises multiple AWS services (Lambda, S3, SQS and DynamoDB) and processes a up to 1 million csv files. As part of the evaluation of the application I would like to calculate the costs associated with each run-through. With that I mean I would like to compare the costs (for all services) when processing 1000, 10000, 100000, etc files.

Apparently other cloud service providers allow for sub-accounts so that the billing is separate which would make it easy to evaluate this for each run-through but AWS doesn't appear to provide this option. Does anyone have an idea how I could separate the billing for each execution?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce tags for various AWS services used by the application and use AWS Cost explorer to get cost per service.

More info on Cost explorer  : https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/

Also you could try AWS simple cost calculator : https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html